# javascript split a string but keep the split character in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following 2 types of lat/long strings

```
2154S15002E

215422N1500232E
```

I wish to split the string on the N or the S, the following works but it drops the N or S so I get an rp array of 2154 15002E, when i want 2154S 15002E

```
var rp = rPoint.split(/\s*(?:N|S)\s*/);
```

How do I split and keep the ‘S’? Or is there a better way than split?

Thank you

Comment: The duplicate uses lookahead to split before the delimiter but it's trivial to use lookbehind to get the split to occur *after* the delimiter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used lookbehind assertions to get split after N or S

```
var rp = rPoint.split(/(?<=[NS])/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just match the pattern of digits and letter.

```js
console.log('2154S15002E'.match(/\d+[SE]/g));
```